# Does "PARTLABEL" affects fstab behavior in Ubuntu16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, fstab, disk

One of my attached disks had `xfs` filesystem. I formatted the disk to `ext4` using:
`sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc1`

Now when I run `sudo -i blkid`, I get this output:

```
/dev/sdc1: UUID="df722345-7e80-4a08-8da1-e6046cc2b0e1" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="xfspart" PARTUUID="1df243b5-2b64-4c39-bd45-4cb31d7ff58e"
```

I can see that the `PARTLABEL` is `xfspart`. Before I make any changes to `fstab`, just want to make sure that `PARTLABEL` won't cause any problem, if I add this line to fstab

`UUID=df722345-7e80-4a08-8da1-e6046cc2b0e1   /disk3   ext4   defaults,nofail   1   2`

Comment: It shouldn't make any problem in `fstab` but I suggest to remove this partition and create again and then format it with ext4. maybe there are some meta data in partition level.

Comment: Can you tell me in detail in the answer section?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PARTLABEL is a property of the partition table (GPT), unrelated to partition content (any filesystem or lvm, luks, raid, etc.). Thus it's not overwritten when you `mkfs` partition content.

If you are not using this value for anything, you can ignore it since it means nothing. Or, to avoid confusion, you can change it with any partition software of your choice.

Example with parted:

```
# parted /dev/loop0 print
Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      1049kB  94.4MB  93.3MB               xfspart
# blkid /dev/loop0p1                                        
/dev/loop0p1: PARTLABEL="xfspart" PARTUUID="a789cf0a-3a18-4b87-af2a-abfed6ca9028"
```

Change the PARTLABEL (partition name in parted) of partition 1 to something else:

```
# parted /dev/loop0 name 1 schnorrgiggl
```

Afterwards:

```
# blkid /dev/loop0p1
/dev/loop0p1: PARTLABEL="schnorrgiggl" PARTUUID="a789cf0a-3a18-4b87-af2a-abfed6ca9028"
# parted /dev/loop0 print
Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name          Flags
 1      1049kB  94.4MB  93.3MB               schnorrgiggl
```

These names also appear under `/dev/disk/by-partlabel` which can be a convenient way to refer to partition block devices. Consider meaningful names like grub, boot, root, home, ... instead of xfspart or extpart which could be anything at all. However, if you use duplicate labels on separate disks, it's unclear which one the partlabel will point to.

PARTUUIDs exists to avoid such naming scheme conflicts, and filesystem UUID is the safest way to refer to a filesystem by content (regardless of where it is stored), so for `/etc/fstab` it's still best to use `UUID=` instead of any `LABEL=`, `PARTLABEL=`, `PARTUUID=` etc. alternatives.

Comment: Thank you very much